# css: icon button in middle of vertical line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an `IconButton` in between the vertical line -

[image]

Currently I use, CSS -

```
.cell-separator {
    border: 1px dotted;
    height: 100%;
}
```

As I add a div for `IconButton`, how can I place it to align in the middle where it elevates the adjacent items in terms of position? Currently, I tried placing a bar with a height of 40% -> IconButton -> 2nd bar with a height of 40%. The icon button doesn't overlap with adjacent items like in the snapshot rather takes full space.

```
<div className={'vertical'}>
    <div
        className={'cell-separator'}
    />
    <div className={'icon-separator'}>
        <IconButton
            iconName={'StatusCircle'}
        />
    </div>
    <div
        className={'cell-separator'}
    />
</div>
```

```
.cell-separator {
    border: 1px dotted;
    height: 50%;
}
```

`Q1:` Is it possible to use one separator div and place a IconButton in middle, or would I need to use two separator divs with 40-50% height and place IconButton in middle?

`Q2:` How to get that overlapping experience with IconButton CSS? Currently it takes whole space in between.

You can use https://codepen.io/prakhar241/pen/JjmMMNK to try out.

Comment: can you add a snippet so I can help you?

Comment: Try https://codepen.io/prakhar241/pen/JjmMMNK

Answer (score 1):

You can make parent (with dotted line) `flex`, add button as child and use `align-items: center;` to get vertically center.

Also you can use `transform` on `btn` to move to center.

```css
.dotted-line {
  position: realative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 40px;
  border-left: dotted 4px green;
  margin-left: 50px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: black;
  transform: translateX(-10px)
}
```

```html
<div class="dotted-line">
  <div class="btn">
  </div>
</div>
```